# Common used class library release method

Tags: c#, .net, reference, release, class-library

I have a class library project, it releases Common.dll file. I use this dll in my another projects. I wonder that which release method is the best?

Compile class library project in release mode

1. and add Common.dll as reference to another projects from dlls Release folder.
2. and copy Common.dll from dlls Release folder to another place and add as reference to another projects from new place.
3. or another method?

All of these methods have positive and negative sides.

If I use 1st method, when I release Common.dll accidentally it overwrites the other projects referenced old version Common.dll.

If I use 2nd method, when I release Common.dll I have to copy it from Release folder and paste to another place. It will be manually and extra work.

Actually maybe all of these methods are wrong but I hope I could explain my problem. I have a Common.dll project which it is referenced another projects. How should I release this dll?

Comment: Make it as a nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Add the Common project to your solution and add a **project reference**: This way you can always edit the Common project and do refactorings.
2. Add the Common.dll as **assembly reference** from your repository: The problem is that you can only reference the newest version (latest) of your assembly (or you reference into another branch).
3. Add the Common.dll as [NuGet package](http://nuget.org): Each package is versioned and you can reference a specific version and only upgrade to a new version if you need to. You can publish the package publicly on nuget.org or you can create your own feed (also possible by using a file directory)